# Sum same values under a condition in a dyadic datastructure

Tags: r

I have the following dyadic dataset:

```
ID.x     Attribute1.x     Attribute2.x    ID.y     Attribute1.y   Attribute2.y   rowsum
2323        11                11           9923        22            11        1
3423        11                22           3422        11            44      1
5343        22                22           5555        11            0        0
54336       0                 44           0234        11            44         1
4334        11                22           2345        44            11           1
34563       22                0            9429        0             22           2
34534       44                0            2345        44            11        1
```

I want to check if the attributes from each column of actor x are the same as from y

```
Attribute1.x == Attribute1.y
Attribute2.x == Attribute2.y
...
```

and sum them into a column "rowsum". My complete dataframe consists out of 100 of Attributes columns for each actor (x,y).

I've tried already and failed somehow:

```
dyadic_df$rowsome <- apply(dat_wp_dyadic_1, 1, function(x) length(which(x==11 & x==22 & x==0 & x==44)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of columns to get lenght of intersect when same within *apply*:

```
# get index
x_index <- grep("^A.*x$", colnames(df1))
y_index <- grep("^A.*y$", colnames(df1))

# loop by row, sort and compare
df1$myRowSum <- 
  apply(df1, 1, function(i){
    length(intersect(i[x_index], i[y_index]))
  })

df1
#    ID.x Attribute1.x Attribute2.x ID.y Attribute1.y Attribute2.y rowsum myRowSum
# 1  2323           11           11 9923           22           11      1        1
# 2  3423           11           22 3422           11           44      1        1
# 3  5343           22           22 5555           11            0      0        0
# 4 54336            0           44  234           11           44      1        1
# 5  4334           11           22 2345           44           11      1        1
# 6 34563           22            0 9429            0           22      2        2
# 7 34534           44            0 2345           44           11      1        1
```

---

**Edit:**

> **OP**: According your suggestion I used sum((i[x_index] == i[y_index])) instead of intersect to sum up how many values per column are exact the same. Now I want to sum up if a condition is fulfilled sum(i[x_index] & i[x_index] == 11 | 22 )

```
mySet <- c(11, 22)

# loop by row, sort and compare
df1$myRowSumFilter <- 
  apply(df1, 1, function(i){
    length(intersect(i[x_index][ i[x_index] %in% mySet ],
                     i[y_index][ i[y_index] %in% mySet ]))
  })

df1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One further question: According your suggestion I used sum((i[x_index] == i[y_index])) instead of intersect to sum up how many values per column are exact the same. Now I want to sum up if a condition is fulfilled sum(i[x_index] & i[x_index]  == 11 | 22 )... but I get an error?!

Comment: @PeteWoods you could keep only `11, 22`s in the vector then check. I will update with an example.

Comment: @PeteWoods post updated with an example, in future avoid asking new questions in the comments.

Comment: thanks again! unfortunately your code gives me a wrong amount. No matter what I put into the "mySet" vector the sum of your condition is always 1 or 0, though the amount should be much higher.. To clearify I want to sum up all pairs of x_index and y_index which have 11 and 22  in common, not only these pairs which share the exactly same value.